# When does Community user protect a question?

Tags: discussion, community-user, protected-questions

I've posted a question (the link to it I'll post later as a comment because I don't think its contents are relevant to this question and I don't want people to visit it needlessly due to the consideration stated here at the bottom) and ever since then, it's been one of my foremost reputation bringers, almost 50k views, starred by a few etc.

I'm happy that I could contribute, especially given the fact that it was one of my first questions on SO what-so-ever.

I've noticed that some questions get managed by the user Community when they become heavily used, well received etc. I understand that the overtake is there in order to ensure the ever raising quality of the site - and I agree with that conduct.

What I wish to know is **when** that occurs so I know how long I'll keep my question as mine. Evidently it's not only a matter of views, stars and upvotes.

Comment: If you see that happen it is a bug as [Automatic conversion to CW no longer happens](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284962/automatic-conversion-to-community-wiki)

Comment: I wonder if I can close this against that post as a duplicate but your question takes a slighty different angle...

Comment: The machine only steps in if a question has an excessive number of answers, too many edits or if it is not marked answered.  None of your high-view questions have those problems.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? The conversion to community wiki? Or other actions by the "Community" account?

Comment: @HansPassant aren't we talking about the same feature? If so, it can't be both enabled and disabled at the same time, unless this is part of an experiment involving the theory of Schrödinger...

Comment: As promised - [this is the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488208/intellisense-doesnt-work-for-javascript-in-visual-studio-2012) that I refer to.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'mnot sure if I understand the question. What I referred to was that some questions are marked as "protected by Community" and Community appears to be a user (if not an individual, perhaps, but rather a system or something). I'm not referring to **wiki conversion** (I think) but to **protection by Community**. Has that answered your questions or did I miss?

Comment: @rene No, please don't. I'm not referring to conversion to wiki (at least not that I'm aware of that it'd be called). I'm talking about the mark that a question is **protected by Community**. I don't think it's the same process as you linked to (but I might be confused as to the technical nomenclature).

Comment: @gnat Perhaps it's a new feature but the protection I was talking about was done by "Community" (the user with a pointy, blue avatar, reputation 1) while the reply linked to points to protection by an actual individual, real avatar, reputation 15k+). Is it still the same kind of protection? If so, then my question is a duplicate and ought to be closed. Otherwise, it's not and calls for an answer.

Comment: @KonradViltersten I [edited the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299516/839601) to explain that

Comment: @KonradViltersten: What do you mean by *"...so I know how long I'll keep my question as mine"*? The question will be yours unless: 1. It's converted to a CW, which seems really unlikely, and you said above that's not what you're asking about. 2. You ask SO to disconnect you from your existing questions/answers. 3. You do something egregious, repeatedly, until SO have no choice but to permanently remove your account (which isn't going to happen :-) ). Being protected doesn't mean the question isn't yours.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Users having over 15K rep can protect questions ([with answers from new users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276978/165773) aka users with < 10 on-site rep) that were posted over a day ago (at some other sites, they can do this earlier than that), see [What kind of questions should be protected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256203/what-kind-of-questions-should-be-protected)

This was the case in example [referred in comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299513/when-does-community-take-over-my-question?noredirect=1#comment221754_299513).

---

As for automatic protection by a [Community user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/community-user/info), it can be triggered in following cases:

- [When the third answer on a question from a new (<10 rep) user is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89971/165773)

  > <sup>There is one tweak though: each user only counts once when we're checking deleted (to eliminate the self-answers that should be comments on their own question case)...</sup>
- [When question gets more than 5 answers from new users in a 24-hour period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228805/165773) (at other sites, amount of answers to trigger this may differ)

  > <sup>i.e. users who earned less than 10 reputation on the site, excluding any association bonuses... The check is run after an answer has been posted on a question - so if an answer by such a user in the last 24 hours has gained an upvote, it will get excluded from the count...</sup>
- [When a question has 2 deleted answers that have been flagged as spam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357942/839601)

  > <sup>We... perform a check when the state of an answer is changed, meaning when an answer is deleted....</sup>

Comment: @gnat I might be explaining it insufficiently clearly but as far I understand, I'm not referring to conversion to wiki. However, I might be ignorant of the actual name of the process and it's possible (although not likely to the best of my recognition) that it's called so.

Comment: related: [How many questions escape community protection because of reputation gained within checked question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238594/165773)

Comment: I think this answer is missing something.  Neither of the specified conditions applied to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39214622/798371), which was protected by the Community user, apparently automatically.

Comment: @WBT having less than 10K rep on that site one can not see deleted answers (three of which could trigger auto-protection). If you want to know whether this was the case in the question you refer ask someone with at least 10K reputation to tell if the question has deleted answers and who posted these