# Is it hard to auto-identify which questions to protect? Is the ability used very rarely?

Tags: support, protected-questions

Here's an example: [Why was the statement (j++); forbidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34422168/why-was-j-forbidden)

As a high rep (10k I think) user I can protect the question to block comments and answers from users with < 10 rep or anonymous users. I have never protected a question and sort of really want to.

Does this feature come up very often at all? I've never felt a need to protect a question. I think I understand *when* to do it as explained in the possible-duplicate. Is it something designed to come up pretty rarely and I'll know the need when I see it? Is there a reason it's not just automated?

tldr, this seems vestigial.

Comment: Protection don't affect comments.

Comment: There is no point in protecting that question, since existing answers and even deleted answers are from high rep users.

Comment: [overview of triggers for automatic protection is here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299516/839601). These were tuned to work pretty reliably at Stack Overflow and catch most of troublesome cases (at other sites these triggers may be less efficient)