# Question protected by Community appears in Review Queue

Tags: discussion, review-queues, first-post-review

I seem to be having bad luck with questions coming up in my review queues lately...

The review item in question is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/13652604 (now I'm having second thoughts about the review...)

The question itself: [My SQL Report Server (ssrs) Does not allow any users other then domain administrators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39123014/my-sql-report-server-ssrs-does-not-allow-any-users-other-then-domain-administr)

The question is asked by a new user, and answered by them. There's a handful of comments, from the OP and one other person. Nothing special, little activity, and yet the question is protected by Community.

1. After reading [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299516/6578301), I can't see a reason why it is protected, though I don't see deleted answers.
2. Why would a protected question end up in a Review Queue? Should this be a thing?

Comment: Why *shouldn't* a protected question be reviewed?  Why does the question being protected mean that there couldn't be anything for you to do as a reviewer?

Comment: I don't know, that's my question :p It seems a little weird, and in the general case where the question has a good reason to be protected, it's unlikely to get any bad quality answers (of course it's not impossible), so there's probably no need to bother reviewers with it. Though in this case I don't know why it's protected in the first place.

Comment: The fact that a question has attracted enough spam (or otherwise problematic answers) to merit being protected means it's all the *more* likely to have problems.  It *has an established history of causing problematic answers*, so why would a question with such a history be *less* likely to have problems of its own?

Comment: You can't see deleted answers, you don't have the ability yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The question has been protected because there were three answers from new users deleted (see below; the answer you currently see has been deleted, but later undeleted, as shown by its [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39127893/timeline)).
2. Because protecting a question only affects possible *answers*, not the question itself, it doesn't say *anything* about the question's quality. Therefore, it should be reviewed as a normal question (providing it meets the criteria for being reviewed, which it apparently does).

> [image]

Answer (score 7):

Questions are protected by the Community user when a certain number of non-answers, spam answers, or trolling posts are deleted from them. In this case, there were two non-answers that had been posted and deleted, triggering the protection.

All that protection does is prevent low-reputation users from leaving answers. It isn't a measure of the quality of the question (spam and non-answers can come in anywhere), and shouldn't impact how you review a question. It's perfectly fine to have protected questions come up in review.