# Has the metric for protecting questions by Community♦ changed?

Tags: support, spam, community-user, protected-questions

I am referring to the question: [save pdf on server using pdfmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46782835/save-pdf-on-server-using-pdfmake).
It received 2 spam answers (one of the user accounts got deleted with the post).

All the posts:[1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question),[2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89532/automatically-protect-questions-with-three-or-more-low-rep-user-deleted-answers/89971#89971) as well as the [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/04/08/changes-and-guidelines-for-the-protected-question-status/) suggests:

> 3 answers from new users deleted – this handles questions that tend to attract large amounts of spam over time.

for the Community♦ to protect it.
Also, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226619/auto-protect-questions-that-get-more-than-n-answers-from-new-users-in-a-24-hour/228805#228805) provides info regarding thresholds for specific SE sites (SO is not specified) which is also at least 3 spam posts in 24 hours.

So what prompted the community♦ to protect the above question?

<sub>For the sake of full context, the question also received 4 vandalism/abusive suggested edits. But I do not believe this had an effect since protecting a question does not prevent suggesting edits</sub>

Comment: info regarding thresholds is specified for SO, you missed it because it is implicit: "Default threshold is 5 answers in 24 hours" (SO isn't listed among specially configured sites meaning it has default threshold)

Comment: @people if you're curious and go out of your way to see these rejected edits, be warned, these are nsfw edits suggestions. here's to me hoping my employer does not parse our internet traffic.

Comment: @gnat in that case as well Community user protected the question very early

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301237/how-many-answers-deleted-as-spam-or-rude-does-it-take-to-automatically-protect-a

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, the metric for protecting questions is still the same. This post was protected because there is a specific check in place for questions that are attracting spam answers.

There are two specific checks for question protection. If a question receives 5 answers by new users within 24 hours, then it meets the requirements for protection. We also perform a check when the state of an answer is changed, meaning when an answer is deleted. On Stack Overflow that check is set to 3, but if a question has 2 answers that have been flagged as spam (not offensive), then we automatically protect the question at that time. This question met that requirement so it was protected.

Comment: nice explanation, thank you! Please consider [edit]ing to additionally clarify whether rude/offensive flags are handled the same or differently. I ask because it seems that system often treats these similarly to spam

Comment: @gnat Edited, it's only spam flagged posts we currently look at.

Comment: would you mind also taking a look at a really tricky case of auto-protection [discussed here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359035/839601)? Two SO mods checked details and as of now it looks like none of known triggers apply

Comment: @gnat There was a bug, it was just fixed.