# Why was this question protected?

Tags: bug, community-user, protected-questions

Today I received notification that a comment had been added to [an answer I provided several years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20102055/asynchronous-request-in-restful-webservice).  When I looked at the question, I saw that right after the comment was added, The question was protected as shown here:

[image]

Why is this?  This one new comment seems useful.  I see no "thanks", "me too" or spam answers.  In fact, there are only 3 answers, with 4 total comments - certainly not a lot of activity.  So I am just curious if there was some automated process that found something wrong.

Comment: ["There was a bug, it was just fixed"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357910/has-the-metric-for-protecting-questions-by-community-changed/357942?noredirect=1#comment530375_357942)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You don't have enough reputation to see the link-only answer that was posted by the same user (who, incidentally, has over 1k rep!) around the same time, and deleted by a moderator, triggering the protection.

(TBH I'm not even sure how effective protecting the question is going to be when users with *over 100 times the threshold for answering protected questions* think posting link-only answers is a good idea. The protection was automated in this case, and I was under the impression it only kicked in when deleting answers by low-rep users, unless something changed recently.)

Comment: They spammed that link to two other questions too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters if at the moment of deletion there were two answers with validated spam flags then I think [this check](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357942/839601) was triggered

Comment: @gnat: there were no spam flags on any of the answers there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters then this protection looks like a real mystery because deletion of non-spam post of an established user [shouldn't trigger any known conditions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299516/839601)

Comment: @gnat: so it looks like something changed.

Comment: @gnat: the 3 deleted answers all have either NAA or VLQ flags.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's not enough per known rules: deleted answers [must be from <10 rep users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89971/165773) to trigger protection (for the sake of completeness, answers from suspended users and from those without account link also qualify)

Comment: @gnat: yes, I know, but that rule clearly doesn't apply here.

Comment: [I asked bluefeet to help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357910/has-the-metric-for-protecting-questions-by-community-changed?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment530006_357942) @MartijnPieters

Comment: I don't see a protection timestamp. Maybe it was protected before the sequence of events folks are assuming. Perhaps on one of the earlier low quality answers triggered the protections. Later, the 1K user came along and answered which folks believed triggered it.

Comment: @jww Just hover over where it says "*x* hours ago". Now that the question has been closed, you'll need to do this on the [revisions page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20102055/revisions).