# In what circumstances does Community User protect a question to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers by new users?

Tags: bug, protected-questions

In what circumstances did our Community User protect this question to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers by new users?

[Python + Selenium: fill text input in the modal form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48439860/python-selenium-fill-text-input-in-the-modal-form)

I have checked the discussion [When does Community user protect my question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299513/when-does-community-user-protect-my-question)

The outcome of both the cases are the same, but the criteria didn't meet with  the clauses as follows :

1. When the third answer on a question from a new (<10 rep) user is deleted.

   Though 3 Answers. Third Answer is undeleted and accepted.
2. When question gets more than 5 answers from new users in a 24-hour period.

   Only 3 answers were on board while 1 answer was from a *Member for 4 months* (not sure if he/she is still considered a new user)
3. When a question has 2 deleted answers that have been flagged as spam.

   1 answer was deleted as a spam. But the second answer was OP's own answer which he/she self deleted.

Can anyone help me out to understand please? Seems to be a bug.

Comment: self answer could have spam flag on it when OP deleted it, this would probably trigger auto-protection (even if later this flag was retracted or cleared by moderator protection would stay)

Comment: IMO, a `spam flag` is still not a valid `spam` until and unless marked `helpful` by our moderators.

Comment: I also think so, intent was probably to count only flags resolved as helpful but there is a good chance that triggering system misses this (eg they may check that flag is neither declined nor disputed thus letting unresolved flags qualify)

Comment: Unresolved `spam` flags qualifying as `spam` is a potential **bug**

Comment: possibly. At the very least (assuming my theory is correct) they need to clarify if this is intended way for the purpose of auto-protection or not (one can in theory argue that for auto-protection it is better to account for unresolved flags)

Comment: The bigger question is - why care? Do you really want a bunch of new users answering your question?

Comment: @theMayer The fact is I like and completely support the functionality. I just wanted to understand the trigger.

Comment: It's kind of a useless feature. It would have been much more useful if the rep was set to 101. Would prevent so many trash answers from cluttering up canonical posts.

Comment: @Lundin canonical posts are expected to be patrolled by 20k users interested in maintaining quality of their tags. They only need to move their a$$es and vote delete trash answers. The only exception are few questions with extremely high views where diamond mods are expected to do cleanup in accordance with [Atwood's guidance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/165773)

Comment: @gnat Last time I tried to clean up trash from canonical duplicates, my attempt was shot down by meta fascists, insisting that we should absolutely not delete crap. So no, it isn't possible for 20k+ users to do that. Anyway, we are derailing from the original topic here.

Comment: @Lundin in highly active tags with enough 20Kers no meta involvement is needed at all. 3 votes delete the garbage answer and that's all

Comment: @gnat No, that is not true. The post I was trying to clean up was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c). It is accessed by both the C and C++ tag followers, which are both very active tags. Yet it is filled up with multiple crap answers. And this is the state that the meta fascists want the post to be in - my meta thread for discussing the clean-up of this post was closed as a dupe to some generic "readme - we must preserve crap" meta post.

Comment: @Lundin as far as I can see about 2/3 low score answers over there are in the reach of 20Kers (3-5 such users could clean it up... if they wanted to). That these answers still stay suggests that either there is no consensus among 20Kers on their usefulness or (which seems more likely) that they don't care

Comment: @gnat Another issue is that there's also lot of high scored answers which are either incorrect or of the nature "here is general advise about something vaguely related to the question". These cannot be trivially removed by users. A diamond mod would have to do it. Which is why I tried to start a meta thread where domain experts could come up with a consensus and then any diamond mod could carry it out. But apparently we don't want high quality technical content on SO, and therefore my attempt to improve the quality of the site was shot down. So I'll refrain from doing such attempts again.

Comment: This is a known bug with how the calculation is done when an answer gets spam-deleted (a second answer being deleted as spam actually ends up being counted twice, when it should only be counted once, which causes the auto-protection to go off regardless of whether the previous deleted answer is new-user-deleted or spam-deleted).

Comment: @animuson Maybe the new, third criterion was implemented very crudely (count any spam-deleted answer as two deleted answers from new users, so that it technically falls under the first criterion and gets protected under that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is sort of an edge-case, but it is slightly buggy (as animuson noted in the comments).

The short answer here is that 3 deleted new user answers will trigger protection... As will two spam-deleted posts... And also: a post by a new user that is deleted as spam *when at least one answer by a new user was also deleted*, whether for spam or for other reasons. That last one is the bug.

The reason for this is that it was convenient to implement this way: before any answer is completely deleted, one check is run that counts up the number of unique authors for any previously-deleted answers and also counts unique authors for any answers with actioned spam flags. And then, if the answer currently being deleted was written by a new user, it adds 1 to this count - because the answer isn't currently deleted yet.

...But the spam flag *has* already been marked as actioned by this point. Which is why protection triggers with only 2 actioned spam-flags... And why a previously-deleted answer by a new user will cause protection if a second answer by a different user is spam-deleted.

Given the description above, you can probably guess at a few other scenarios where the behavior of auto-protect won't quite match the documentation: for instance, you could in theory have *dozens* of spam-answers by the same author all deleted and never see an auto-protect. Or auto-protect kicking in on a *single* deleted answer if there were a big ol' pile of previously spam-deleted answers that'd been rescued sitting around (but ONLY if the moderator who rescued them forgot to clear the spam flags when doing so).

But as I said at the start, these are edge-cases; they mostly don't happen and mostly don't matter.